# How do I group objects into nested objects by a value in the object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumeration

Here's an object I'm working with in Ruby. It's a bunch of events sorted by date, but I want to nest the object one level deeper when there are two or more with the same event_type next to each other in the object.

```
@events = [ 
    { :id => 1, :event_type => "B", :created_at => "2013-09-30 14:44:24 UTC"},
    { :id => 2, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-29 14:44:24 UTC"},
    { :id => 3, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-28 14:44:24 UTC"},
    { :id => 4, :event_type => "C", :created_at => "2013-09-27 14:44:24 UTC"},
    { :id => 5, :event_type => "C", :created_at => "2013-09-26 14:44:24 UTC"},
    { :id => 6, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-25 14:44:24 UTC"}
]
```

I'm looking to turn it into this:

```
@events = [
    { :id => 1, :event_type => "B", :created_at => "2013-09-30 14:44:24 UTC"},
    { :grouped_events => [
            { :id => 2, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-29 14:44:24 UTC"},
                { :id => 3, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-28 14:44:24 UTC"}
            ]
        },
    { :grouped_events => [
            { :id => 4, :event_type => "C", :created_at => "2013-09-27 14:44:24 UTC"},
            { :id => 5, :event_type => "C", :created_at => "2013-09-26 14:44:24 UTC"}
            ]
        },
    { :id => 6, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-25 14:44:24 UTC"}
]
```

I need the overall object to keep the nested objects sorted by date, but if there are 2 or more events clustered together, I want them turned into an array, as seen by the sample output.
It seems like a simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can't have two keys with the same name (`:event`)

Comment: @Scott, I have no idea if you'd find it preferable (and you probably considered this), but you could instead have `@events = [[{:id => 1,..UTC"}], [{:id => 2,..UTC"}, :id => 3,..UTC"}], [{:id => 4,..UTC"}, {:id => 5,..UTC"}], [{:id => ..UTC"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep order use [chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) method of `Enumerable`:

```
@events = [ 
 { :id => 1, :event_type => "B", :created_at => "2013-09-30 14:44:24 UTC"},
 { :id => 1, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-29 14:44:24 UTC"},
 { :id => 1, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-28 14:44:24 UTC"},
 { :id => 1, :event_type => "C", :created_at => "2013-09-27 14:44:24 UTC"},
 { :id => 1, :event_type => "C", :created_at => "2013-09-26 14:44:24 UTC"},
 { :id => 1, :event_type => "A", :created_at => "2013-09-25 14:44:24 UTC"}
]

p @events.chunk{|el| el[:event_type]}.map{|gr| gr[1]}
```

Output:

```
#=> [[{:id=>1, :event_type=>"B", :created_at=>"2013-09-30 14:44:24 UTC"}], 
#=>  [{:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-29 14:44:24 UTC"}, 
#=>   {:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-28 14:44:24 UTC"}], 
#=>  [{:id=>1, :event_type=>"C", :created_at=>"2013-09-27 14:44:24 UTC"}, 
#=>   {:id=>1, :event_type=>"C", :created_at=>"2013-09-26 14:44:24 UTC"}], 
#=>  [{:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-25 14:44:24 UTC"}]]
```

Or, if you like to have arrays only when there 2 or more elements try this:

```
p @events
  .chunk{|el| el[:event_type]}
  .flat_map{|gr| gr[1].length == 1 ? gr[1] : [gr[1]]}
```

Output will be

```
#=> [
#=>    {:id=>1, :event_type=>"B", :created_at=>"2013-09-30 14:44:24 UTC"}, 
#=>   [{:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-29 14:44:24 UTC"}, 
#=>    {:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-28 14:44:24 UTC"}], 
#=>   [{:id=>1, :event_type=>"C", :created_at=>"2013-09-27 14:44:24 UTC"}, 
#=>    {:id=>1, :event_type=>"C", :created_at=>"2013-09-26 14:44:24 UTC"}], 
#=>    {:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-25 14:44:24 UTC"}
#=> ]
```

**Update**

You change output format on the fly :)

For your last variant try this:

```
p @events
  .chunk{|el| el[:event_type]}
  .flat_map{|gr| 
    gr[1].length == 1 ? gr[1] : {:grouped_events => gr[1]}
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry for changing the output on you...realized I needed something a tiny bit different. Love your approach here!

Comment: It's OK. By the way, your data are wrong. There couldn't be `...:event_type = "B"...`, it should be `...:event_type => "B"...`.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
p @events.group_by{|item| item[:event_type]}.values #=>

# [[{:id=>1, :event_type=>"B", :created_at=>"2013-09-30 14:44:24 UTC"}],
# [{:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-29 14:44:24 UTC"},
#  {:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-28 14:44:24 UTC"},
#  {:id=>1, :event_type=>"A", :created_at=>"2013-09-25 14:44:24 UTC"}],
# [{:id=>1, :event_type=>"C", :created_at=>"2013-09-27 14:44:24 UTC"},
#  {:id=>1, :event_type=>"C", :created_at=>"2013-09-26 14:44:24 UTC"}]]
```

Comment: This groups the events by event type, without taking into account the order of the events. I need to have the events sorted by date AND event_type.

Comment: Ohh, missed that part. Same thing but the method you are looking for is chunk, look at Yevgeniy Anfilofyev's answer.